# FreeBSD - how do I compile PolyML including XWindows module

Tags: freebsd, polyml

On freebsd 12 the xwindows module in PolyML is not implemented so I am trying to compile its source outside the ports tree. It does compile, but I cannot open the XWindows module in poly.

What I did is:

- copied libX11 to /usr/lib to be sure, and made symbolic links in
  /usr/include for Xm and X11 to /usr/local/include.
- inserted one space in xwindows.cpp because of a clang error
- added these options to configure :
  --x-includes=/usr/local/include/X11 --x-libraries=/usr/local/lib/   --with-x --with-system-libffi
- set the environment : LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib/gcc7 , where libstdc++
  is located
- tried with clang and gcc7

The code compiles without further errors. There is a file xwindows.o, 375160 bytes for cc and 291184 for gcc7.
The log contains
Created structure XWindows
Created structure Motif

I run poly from where it was compiled, and get
open XWindows
poly: : error: Structure (XWindows) has not been declared Found near open XWindows.

The non-graphics modules open normally

What am i doing wrong here ?? thanks for pointers

Comment: There is already `lang/polyml` port: https://www.freshports.org/lang/polyml/ Doesn't it suit for you?

Comment: @arrowd That is the one I used, but XWindows is disabled in it

Comment: It seems that `MOTIF` option does exactly what you want. But you'll need to compile this software from ports by running `make -C /usr/ports/lang/polyml config install clean`.

Comment: @arrowd The MOTIF option is set in the port, vd `Makefile:OPTIONS_DEFINE= MOTIF`                                                           
`MOTIF_CONFIGURE_WITH=   x`                                                       
`MOTIF_USE=              motif`                                                   
after compilation however, 'strings xwindows.o' shows `Not implemented`
`xwindows.cpp`
`PolyXWindowsGeneral`
zPLR

Comment: `OPTIONS_DEFINE` only declares an option. You should enable it in `make config` dialog and then compile a port. Have you done this?

Comment: @arrowd Thanks, I indeed had omitted a `make rmconfig` . After this, I could compile from the port directory, and I made two changes to get my result

Answer (score 0):

I

1. added CONFIGURE_ENV= LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib to the port's Makefile, and
2. inserted a space before ZERO_X in xwindows.cpp

after which the ports code compiled, including the 2 modules in poly

My error has been to omit a make rmconfig before new compilation, and I had originally compiled poly without motif, so that kept coming back